# As $ b$ varies range of $m(b)$ is?

Tags: calculus, functions

Let $f(x)=(1+b^2)x^2+2bx+1$ and let $m(b)$ be the minimum value of $f(x)$.As $b$ varies range of $m(b)$ is ?

I can find the minima by putting $f'(x)=0$ and hence find $m(b)$.But after that i'm not able to find range of $m(b)$.

Comment: Is this correct: Range: [0,1) ?

Comment: Are you sure it is the minima you are finding by putting $f'(x)=0$ ?

Comment: Since the coefficient of $x^2$ is positive you know that the parabola is concave up so the vertex is the lowest point of the graph, so $m(b)$ is just the $y$ coordinate of the vertex when the derivative is $0$. If you express that as a function of $b$ I believe you will see what range of values it can take.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Finding minimum :**

$$f(x)=(1+b^2)x^2+2bx+1$$

$$f(x)=(1+b^2)\left[x^2+\frac{2b}{1+b^2}x+\frac{1}{1+b^2}\right]$$

$$f(x)=(1+b^2)\left[\left(x+\frac{b}{1+b^2}\right)^2-\frac{b^2}{(1+b^2)^2}+\frac{1}{1+b^2}\right]$$

$$f(x)=(1+b^2)\left[\left(x+\frac{b}{1+b^2}\right)^2-\frac{b^2}{(1+b^2)^2}+\frac{1+b^2}{(1+b^2)^2}\right]$$

$$f(x)=(1+b^2)\left[\left(x+\frac{b}{1+b^2}\right)^2+\frac{b^2}{(1+b^2)^2}\right]$$

Thus $$f(x)=(1+b^2)\left(x+\frac{b}{1+b^2}\right)^2+\frac{1}{1+b^2}$$

Since $$\left(x+\frac{b}{1+b^2}\right)^2 \geq 0$$

$$(1+b^2)\left(x+\frac{b}{1+b^2}\right)^2 \geq 0$$

$$(1+b^2)\left(x+\frac{b}{1+b^2}\right)^2+\frac{1}{1+b^2} \geq \frac{1}{1+b^2}$$

$$f(x) \geq \frac{1}{1+b^2}$$

Therefore $$f(x)_{min}=m(b)=\frac{1}{1+b^2}$$

**Finding the range of the minimum :**

Now take $y=m(b)$ , for all real $b$ ,

$$y=\frac{1}{1+b^2} \Rightarrow y+yb^2=1$$

$$yb^2+y-1=0$$

Since $b$ is a variable , this is a quadratic equation of $b$.

Thus for all real $b$ , its discriminant must be greater than or equal to zero.

That is , $$0^2-4y(y-1) \geq 0$$

$$(y-1)y \leq 0$$

Thus $$0 < y \leq 1$$

Comment: I think you have calculated the m(b) incorrectly.m(0) should be 1 not 0.

Comment: @TushantMittal Edited

Comment: (+1) To use discriminants in order to avoid derivatives is a very under-estimated technique.

Answer (score 2):

The minima occurs at$\frac{-b}{1+b^2}$
Substituting this we get,
$$m(b)=1-\frac{b^2}{1+b^2} $$

$$m(b)=\frac{1}{1+b^2} $$
Therefore range of m(b)=(0,1]